# Incorrect data type for operator or @function time/date expected on lotusscript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

In lotusScript: I've used:

```
doc.DocDate = Format(document.get("DatePublished"),"mm/dd/yyyy") 'Rem return 08/22/2017
```

In formula: I've used for to get year:

```
@Year(DocDate)
```

But when i run the program i get the error : "incorrect data type for operator or @function time/date expected". How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Get date value with

```
document.DatePublished(0)
```

or

```
document.GetItemValue("DatePublished")(0)
```

Then your field DocDate should be calculated properly.

`@Year()` expects a NotesDateTime value. DocDate is a String value though. You can change your formula to

```
@Year(@ToTime(DocDate))
```

and it will work if your language settings are set to US date format.