# Field cannot be read as it show error "incorrect data type for operator or @function time/date expected" when try to open new form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I'm trying to open a new blank form using formula: @Command([@Compose];"Computer") but it pop up error message as below:

"Field: 'PDateEnd': Incorrect data type for operator or @Function: Time/Date expected"

Inside my form, I have three field to count difference between two date.
The field is as below:

[image: first]

PStartDate: Computed for display with @Today formula.
The first field is current date. So it will update day to today everytime document is open.

PDateEnd: Editable with formula @Date(PDateEnd)
The second field is date set by user. So it can be edit.

PMonitorWarranty: Computed for display with formula:
@Abs(@Integer((PDateEnd - PStartDate) / (86400)))

I'm try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808556/incorrect-data-type-for-operator-or-function-time-date-expected-on-lotusscript) but it show another error: "Field: 'PDateEnd': Unable to interpret Time or Date"

Why is there is error on my PDateEnd? Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows up when your field PDateEnd is empty.

Check in your formula first if PDateEnd is empty and calculate time difference only if it's not:

```
@If(PDateEnd = ""; ""; @Abs(@Integer((PDateEnd - PStartDate) / (86400))))
```

Comment: Also, the @Date(PDateEnd) formula probably fails too when PDateEnd is empty

Comment: Yes it still show the same error. Is there any other way to use other than @Date(PDateEnd)?

Comment: Okay nevermind. I manage to solve it. Because my PDateEnd is editable field. So I just remove the formula. Thanks for you answer.